# VBA: Check if files exist

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm creating a PowerPoint presentation which gets data and slides from different Excel and PowerPoint files. The basic code works, now I have to clean it up and deal with issues like "what if the file doesn't exist?"

In this regard I need some advice. I want two things to happen: I want the user to know about the missing files, but also that the code continues executing (one missing file shouldn't derail the whole macro). How do I do this in a clean/readable way?

My idea would be to check if the files exist before the actual code with something like

```
If Dir("File Path") = "" Then
   MsgBox "File doesn't exist"
```

However, in this case I also need the macro to skip the part of the code with the missing file(s). In the initial check I could create a variable like `File1Exists = True`, that switches to `False` if the file doesn't exist. And then for each part of code/each sub, I could do an If-statement to check if this condition is true or not.

That should work, but is that really the best solution? Seems like a bunch of code for such a simple issue. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, i would suggest using your own `if` statement... `If Dir("File Path") = "" Then
   MsgBox "File doesn't exist" Else RunMyCodeAsNeeded End If`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
Dim file_exists as Boolean
file_exists = (Dir("File Path") <> "")

If file_exists Then
  ....
Else
  ....
End If
```